# Drawing 3D cylinder

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, 3d

I need to draw a lot of 3D cylinders with different dimensions.
Has anyone maybe already defined a command like `\3Dcylinder{x}{y}{z}`?

I found [3D bodies in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42812/3d-bodies-in-tikz/62339#62339)
and tried the third answer. But I don't understand how the parameters work.

Also I found [Drawing simple 3D cylinders in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31548/drawing-simple-3d-cylinders-in-tikz).
But I don't know how to use it to easily draw a bunch of different cylinders.

Comment: You might be interested in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129860/5645

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also once had that problem when I had to draw an explded view drawing. **Andrew Stacey**'s answer in the second link you mentioned was the way to go, so I adapted the following macro:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\xdeg}{30}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xx}{cos(\xdeg)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xy}{sin(\xdeg)}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\ydeg}{120}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yx}{cos(\ydeg)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yy}{sin(\ydeg)}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\zdeg}{80}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\zx}{cos(\zdeg)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\zy}{sin(\zdeg)}

\newcommand{\tdcyl}[5]{% origin x, origin y, origin z, radius, height
    \path (1,0,0);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\cylxx}{\cylxy}
    \path (0,1,0);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\cylyx}{\cylyy}
    \path (0,0,1);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\cylzx}{\cylzy}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cylt}{(\cylzy * \cylyx - \cylzx * \cylyy)/ (\cylzy * \cylxx - \cylzx * \cylxy)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ang}{atan(\cylt)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ct}{1/sqrt(1 + (\cylt)^2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\st}{\cylt * \ct}
    \filldraw[fill=white] (#4*\ct+#1,#4*\st+#2,#3) -- ++(0,0,#5) arc[start angle=\ang,delta angle=-180,radius=#4] -- ++(0,0,-#5) arc[start angle=\ang+180,delta angle=180,radius=#4];
    \filldraw[fill=white] (#1,#2,#3+#5) circle[radius=#4];
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(\xx*1cm,\xy*1cm)},y={(\yx*1cm,\yy*1cm)},z={(\zx*1cm,\zy*1cm)}]
    \tdcyl{0}{0}{0}{1}{3}
    \draw (-3,0,0) -- (3,0,0) node[circle,fill=white] {x};
    \draw (0,-3,0) -- (0,3,0) node[circle,fill=white] {y};
    \draw (0,0,-3) -- (0,0,3) node[circle,fill=white] {z};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note however that this only works for cylinders growing in z-direction and "right handed" coordinate systems, e.g. when in a clockwise fashion the vectors are yzx, zxy or xyz, but not yxz, zxy or xzy.

---

**Edit 1**: As I remembered that I also had to draw y-growing cylinders, I looked it up. Being too lazy to generalize the macro, I then just redefined the coordinate axes locally thus changling the order of th input meaning (from `xyz`rh for z-growing to `xzy`rh for y-growing and `yzx`rh for x-growing), and I also had to modify the original macro. Probably one could unify these (probably involving something like `ifthenelse` from `xifthen` package). For now, here's the ugly hackish version, I recommaned not using it or documenting very well what you did:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\xdeg}{30}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xx}{cos(\xdeg)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xy}{sin(\xdeg)}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\ydeg}{150}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yx}{cos(\ydeg)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yy}{sin(\ydeg)}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\zdeg}{90}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\zx}{cos(\zdeg)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\zy}{sin(\zdeg)}

\newcommand{\tdcyl}[5]{% origin x, origin y, origin z, radius, height
    \path (1,0,0);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\cylxx}{\cylxy}
    \path (0,1,0);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\cylyx}{\cylyy}
    \path (0,0,1);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\cylzx}{\cylzy}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cylt}{(\cylzy * \cylyx - \cylzx * \cylyy)/ (\cylzy * \cylxx - \cylzx * \cylxy)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ang}{atan(\cylt)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ct}{1/sqrt(1 + (\cylt)^2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\st}{\cylt * \ct}
    \filldraw[fill=white] (#4*\ct+#1,#4*\st+#2,#3) -- ++(0,0,#5) arc[start angle=\ang,delta angle=-180,radius=#4] -- ++(0,0,-#5) arc[start angle=\ang+180,delta angle=180,radius=#4];
    \filldraw[fill=white] (#1,#2,#3+#5) circle[radius=#4];
}

\newcommand{\tdcylxy}[5]{% origin x, origin y, origin z, radius, height
    \path (1,0,0);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\cylxx}{\cylxy}
    \path (0,1,0);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\cylyx}{\cylyy}
    \path (0,0,1);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\cylzx}{\cylzy}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cylt}{(\cylzy * \cylyx - \cylzx * \cylyy)/ (\cylzy * \cylxx - \cylzx * \cylxy)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ang}{atan(\cylt)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ct}{1/sqrt(1 + (\cylt)^2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\st}{\cylt * \ct}
    \filldraw[fill=white] (#4*\ct+#1,#4*\st+#2,#3) -- ++(0,0,#5) arc[start angle=\ang,delta angle=180,radius=#4] -- ++(0,0,-#5) arc[start angle=\ang+180,delta angle=180,radius=#4];
    \filldraw[fill=white] (#1,#2,#3) circle[radius=#4];
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(\xx*1cm,\xy*1cm)},y={(\yx*1cm,\yy*1cm)},z={(\zx*1cm,\zy*1cm)}]
    \tdcyl{0}{0}{3}{1}{3} % x y z   r h
    \begin{scope}[x={(\xx*1cm,\xy*1cm)},z={(\yx*1cm,\yy*1cm)},y={(\zx*1cm,\zy*1cm)}]
        % This is a y-growing cylinder
        \tdcylxy{0}{0}{3}{1.5}{3} % x z y r h
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[z={(\xx*1cm,\xy*1cm)},x={(\yx*1cm,\yy*1cm)},y={(\zx*1cm,\zy*1cm)}]
        % This is a x-growing cylinder
        \tdcylxy{0}{0}{3}{0.5}{3} % y z x  r h
    \end{scope}
    \draw (-3,0,0) -- (3,0,0) node[circle,fill=white] {x};
    \draw (0,-3,0) -- (0,3,0) node[circle,fill=white] {y};
    \draw (0,0,-3) -- (0,0,3) node[circle,fill=white] {z};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

You may also use the cylinder shape. Here are two examples, taken directly from the tikz manual.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

￼￼\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[cylinder, draw, shape aspect=.5] {ABC};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [cylinder, gray!50, rotate=30, draw,
    minimum height=2cm, minimum width=1cm] (c) {Cylinder};
  \draw[red, <->] (c.top)   -- (c.bottom)
    node [at end, below, black]   {height};
  \draw[red, <->] (c.north) -- (c.south)
    node [at start, above, black] {width};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]