# How to draw a 3d cylinder using TikZ-3dplot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, tikz-3dplot

I'm trying to draw a 3d cylinder using TikZ-3dplot, but the cylinder walls are not aligned properly (as you can see in the image).

Does anybody knows what am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\thetadisp}{60}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\phidisp}{170}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{\thetadisp}{\phidisp}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\rvec}{.8}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\thetavec}{15}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\phivec}{30}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=10,tdplot_main_coords]

    \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0) node[anchor=north]{$o$};

    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=east]{$x$};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south east]{$z$};

    \tdplotsetcoord{P}{\rvec}{\thetavec}{\phivec};
    \draw[thick,color=gray,->] (O) -- (P);

    \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\phivec}{\thetavec}{0}

    \tdplotsetcoord{A}{0.2}{90+\thetavec}{0};
    \draw[thin,tdplot_rotated_coords,fill=gray] (A) arc[start angle=0,delta angle=180,radius=.2] -- ++(0,0,\rvec) arc[start angle=180,delta angle=-180,radius=.2] -- cycle;
    \draw[thin,tdplot_rotated_coords,fill=green] (0,0,\rvec) circle[radius=.2];

    \draw[thick,tdplot_rotated_coords,->] (0,0,0) -- (.2,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x'$};
    \draw[thick,tdplot_rotated_coords,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,.2,0) node[anchor=west]{$y'$};
    \draw[thick,tdplot_rotated_coords,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,.2) node[anchor=south west]{$z'$};    

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63370/drawing-3d-cylinder and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31548/drawing-simple-3d-cylinders-in-tikz

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: [3D bodies in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42812/3d-bodies-in-tikz)