# Is it possible to draw a 3d cylinder using TikZ-3dplot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, tikz-3dplot

I want to draw a clyinder between two planes. I want to specify the distance between the planes and position and radius of the cylinder.

[image: Result]

I would like to use tikz-3dplot, because it allows a free rotation of the Viewpoint if everything is implemented with it.

There are a few Threads in which the creation of [3D bodies in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42812/3d-bodies-in-tikz), [Drawing simple 3D cylinders in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31548/drawing-simple-3d-cylinders-in-tikz) and [Drawing 3D cylinder](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63370/drawing-3d-cylinder) have been discussed.

Unfortunately those solution seem not to work with tikz-3dplot, because they all manipulate the 'Viewpoint' themself. This leads to the Problem, that a manipulation of the viewpoint with \tdplotsetmaincoords only rotates all Objects except the Cylinders.

[image: Result at the moment with tikz]
[image: Result at the moment with Tikz - front view]

Another User had a very similar question which yielded no answer yet. 
[How to draw a 3d cylinder using TikZ-3dplot?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109828/how-to-draw-a-3d-cylinder-using-tikz-3dplot?lq=1)

To summarize: I want to draw a cylinder in 3d using tikz-3dplot. At the Moment i can draw the circle at the end of the cylinder and a line from border to border, which only recognizes rotation around the x-axis. The Question is how can i put the lines correctly at the side of the cylinder. 
[image: Solution at the moment]

Example of Code:

```
\documentclass[convert = false, tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}

%Configure here Rotation around x and y axis
\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{60}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{100}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{\x}{\y}

\begin{tikzpicture}[ tdplot_main_coords]

  \coordinate (O) at (0, 0, 0);

    \draw[-latex] (O) -- (-8, 0, 0) node[font = \small, pos = 1.1] {\(x\)};
    \draw[-latex] (O) -- (0, 6, 0) node[font = \small, pos = 1.1] {\(y\)};
    \draw[-latex] (O) -- (0, 0, 6) node[font = \small, pos = 1.1] {\(z\)};

    % define size of planes
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\planesize}{4}

    %plane1
    \filldraw[blue, opacity = .2]
         (0, 0, 0)
          -- (0, \planesize, 0)
          -- (0, \planesize, \planesize)
          -- (0, 0, \planesize)
          -- cycle;


    %Define Plane in which the circles of the cylinder are drawn.
    \tdplotgetpolarcoords{0}{1}{0}
    \tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{\tdplotresphi}

    %\tdplotdrawarc[coordinate system, draw styles]{center}{r}{angle start}{angle end}{label options}{label}
    %circle on first plane
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\radius}{0.5}
    \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(1,1,0)}{\radius}{0}%
    {360}{}{}

    %circle on second plane  
    \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(1,1,4)}{\radius}{0}%
    {360}{}{}

    %line from middle to middle
    \draw[tdplot_rotated_coords] (1,1,0) -- (1, 1, 4) node[font = \small, pos = 1.1] {};

    %First Edge of cylinder
     \draw[tdplot_rotated_coords] 
     ({1+sin(\x)*\radius},
      {1+cos(\x)*\radius},0)
       -- 
     ({1+sin(\x)*\radius},
      {1+cos(\x)*\radius},
       4) 
     node[font = \small, pos = 1.1] {};


    %plane2
    \filldraw[blue, opacity = .2]
             (-4, 0, 0)
              -- (-4, \planesize, 0)
              -- (-4, \planesize, \planesize)
              -- (-4, 0, \planesize)
              -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sebastian, you're welcome, but that comment should be a comment and not part of the question. Secondly, could you please explain why you included my solution in your question? I'm having a hard time trying to figure out the problem here. :P (You can comment below here.)

Comment: @Alemanno i basically want a way to draw the first picture and be able to expand it to three planes and multiple cylinders. I thought that Tikz-3dplot would be the best way to do something like that. Unfortunately there seems to be no support for cylinders. That's the reason why I am trying to construct them myself and why i am asking for help. I will abandon tikz in a blink if you know a better tool to do the job. I only know Blender, but that would be overkill i guess.

Comment: Showing a mock-up of your desired final result would be helpful. Your first image looks like the one I've been doing so I'm not sure what you want exactly. :D

Comment: @Alenanno i reformulated everything. The Problem is, that it's just a coincidence, that the Picture in your Answer looks correct. The Coordinates of the circle and of the plane are completly different.

Answer (score 6):

Attempted with `pgfplots`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    view={45}{30},
    axis equal image,
    axis lines=center,
    xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,ztick=\empty,
    colormap={white}{color=(white)color=(white)},
    mesh/interior colormap={blue}{color=(blue!20)color=(blue!20)},
    z buffer=sort]
    \addplot3 [domain=0:8,y domain=0:8,surf,opacity=0.6,shader=flat,samples=2] (x,8,y);
    \addplot3 [domain=0:8,y domain=0:2*pi,mesh,black,samples=25] ({4+1*cos(deg(y))},{8},{4+1*sin(deg(y))});
    \addplot3 [domain=0:8,y domain=0:2*pi,surf,shader=interp,samples=25] ({4+1*cos(deg(y))},{x},{4+1*sin(deg(y))});
    \addplot3 [domain=0:8,y domain=0:8,surf,opacity=0.6,shader=flat,samples=2] (x,0,y); 
    \addplot3 [domain=0:8,y domain=0:2*pi,mesh,black,samples=25] ({4+1*cos(deg(y))},{0},{4+1*sin(deg(y))});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image]

### **Remark:**

Commands

```
\addplot3 [domain=0:8,y domain=0:8,surf,opacity=0.6,shader=flat,samples=2] (x,0,y);
```

and

```
\addplot3 [domain=0:8,y domain=0:8,surf,opacity=0.6,shader=flat,samples=2] (x,8,y);
```

draw planes y=0 and y=8. While command

```
\addplot3 [domain=0:8,y domain=0:2*pi,surf,shader=interp,samples=25] ({4+1*cos(deg(y))},{x},{4+1*sin(deg(y))});{x},{4+1*sin(deg(y))});
```

drawing a cylinder (a+bcos(y),x,a+bsin(y)), where a=4 and b=1. I also added:

```
\addplot3 [domain=0:8,y domain=0:2*pi,mesh,black,samples=25] ({4+1*cos(deg(y))},{0},{4+1*sin(deg(y))});
\addplot3 [domain=0:8,y domain=0:2*pi,mesh,black,samples=25] ({4+1*cos(deg(y))},{8},{4+1*sin(deg(y))});
```

to mark where the cylinder and plane intercept, as `pgfplots` couldn't handle that automatically.

You can rotate the view point freely by changing the `view={...}{...}` option. For example, `view={60}{30}` will give you:

[image]

Most of the options of `pgfplots` are quite self-explanatory, refer to the package document for further detail.

Comment: Is it possible to blacken the "edge" of the cylinder? So that the tube is transparent and only two lines connect both circles of the cylinder?

Comment: @SebastianSchmitz: You can use options such as `mesh` or `shader=faceted` to emphasize the edges. But unfortunately that will mark all the line that are sampled. As far as I know there is no way to remove all the edges except two.

Answer (score 6):

The following answer uses Asymptote rather than TikZ-3dplot, but otherwise does (I think) everything you ask.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}

\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
defaultpen(fontsize(10pt));
settings.render=0;
settings.prc=false;
size(8cm);

import solids;

//currentprojection = obliqueX(angle=55);
currentprojection = orthographic(2X+Y+Z);

path3 xaxis = O -- -6X;
draw(xaxis, arrow=Arrow3);
label(Label("$x$", position=EndPoint), xaxis);

path3 yaxis = O -- 6Y;
draw(yaxis, arrow=Arrow3);
label(Label("$y$", position=EndPoint), yaxis);

path3 zaxis = O -- 6Z;
draw(zaxis, arrow=Arrow3);
label(Label("$z$", position=EndPoint), zaxis);


triple circlecenter = Y+Z;
real radius = 0.5;
triple normal = -X;
// center = Y+Z, radius=0.5, height=4, normal=-X
revolution cylinder = cylinder(circlecenter, radius, 4, normal);

surface plane = surface(O -- 4Y -- 4Y+4Z -- 4Z -- cycle);
material planecolor = material(lightblue+opacity(0.5), emissivepen=lightblue);
draw(shift(-4X) * plane, planecolor);

//Block out everything behind the cylinder.
draw(surface(cylinder), emissive(white));

draw(plane, planecolor);

draw(surface(circle(circlecenter, radius, normal)), emissive(white));

draw(cylinder.silhouette());

\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

If you change the projection (by changing which of the two lines starting `currentprojection =` is commented out), you get the following:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Not sure how to answer the "theoretical" part of your question because I'm not really an expert on this subject. But if you simply wanted a solution to make your cylinder look good, then maybe I found one.

It's not the best and it's actually just a sort of "hack/trick" but it works.

[image: cylinder image]

What I changed was to move the cylinder code (the one below) to before the `filldraw` commands:

```
\begin{scope}[z={(\xx*1cm,\xy*1cm)},x={(\yx*1cm,\yy*1cm)},y={(\zx*1cm,\zy*1cm)}]
    % This is a x-growing cylinder
    \tdcylxy{0}{0}{2}{0.5}{3} % y z x  r h
\end{scope}
```

And then repost the same code after the `filldraw` commands, but this time changing the H value to `0`, so that the circle appears in front.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to **avoid manual or sophisticated calculation of boundaries** when drawing the projected cylinder. To this end, let me show a robust way with `tikz-3dplot` library (adapted from my [other post](https://skorski.lu/2023/07/16/easy-and-correct-cylinders-in-latex/)):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}

\def\rotx{70}
\def\rotz{110}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{\rotx}{\rotz}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords][scale=0.75]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\small]
\draw[dashed,-latex] (0,0,0) -- (6,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
\draw[dashed,-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,6,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
\draw[dashed,-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,6) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
\draw [thick](0,0,0) circle (3);
\draw [thick](0,0,4) circle (3);
% manual edges
\draw [dotted](1.9,-2.34,0) -- (1.9,-2.34,4) node[midway, left]{};
\draw [dotted](-1.9,2.35,0) -- (-1.9,2.35,4);
% automatic edges !
\pgfcoordinate{edge1_top}{ \pgfpointcylindrical{\rotz}{3}{4} };
\pgfcoordinate{edge1_bottom}{ \pgfpointcylindrical{\rotz}{3}{0} };
\draw[thick] (edge1_top) -- (edge1_bottom);
\pgfcoordinate{edge2_top}{ \pgfpointcylindrical{\rotz+180}{3}{4} };
\pgfcoordinate{edge2_bottom}{ \pgfpointcylindrical{\rotz+180}{3}{0} };
\draw[thick] (edge2_top) -- (edge2_bottom);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This gives us
[image]