# draw cone with gradient fill in latex, tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [3D bodies in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42812/3d-bodies-in-tikz)

How can I draw the following diagram in latex (obviously will look better when drawn in latex), considering I would like to annotate the diagram with text and arrows etc?

[image]

The main difficulties i'm facing is finding an efficient way of drawing a cone, for example when I draw this in powerpoint I had to insert a triangle and then overlay a circle to create the cone. There must be a better way in latex, with tikz?

Comment: Dear Kate, please show us what you have been producing so far. It makes it a lot easier for people to see what you have tried. (as a side note, you could scour texample.net which I believe have something similar)

Comment: With Tikz, you can do the same as in powerpoint: draw first a filled triangle, then a circle (ellipse here)

Comment: Shaded cones have been drawn in [3D bodies in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42812/3d-bodies-in-tikz), so I suggest to close this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is my solution based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42865/22492) answer.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \shade[top color=blue!40!white,opacity=0.75] (-1,0) arc (180:0:1cm and 0.5cm) -- (0,-3) -- cycle;
        \draw [thick](-1,0) arc (180:360:1cm and 0.5cm) -- (0,-3) -- cycle;
        \draw [thick](-1,0) arc (180:0:1cm and 0.5cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Pouya the edges of the cone are a bit visible through the base. I think a better result can be obtained by drawing first a shaded triangle, and then painting a filled ellipse on top of it for the base.