# Draw sphere with some portion is dotted

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to draw the following figure :
[image]

I have used the following code to get it :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (2,2) circle (3cm);
\draw (2,2) ellipse (3cm and 1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces :

[image]

How can I draw my desired figure using tikzpicture ?

Is there any way to draw an arbitrary curve with some portion of it is dotted?

Comment: Would this be helpful? http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42812/34618 and related links there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case, it is very simple to draw the ellipse twice, and clip the solid part, so only half of it is shown.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (2,2) circle (3cm);
\draw[dashed] (2,2) ellipse (3cm and 1cm);
\clip (-1.1,2) rectangle (5.1 cm,0.9 cm);
\draw (2,2) ellipse (3cm and 1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: An other solution(and better) is to draw only the 180 degrees you need - once solid, and once dashed. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42812/3d-bodies-in-tikz

Comment: Thank you @Hans-PeterE.K. Your answer helped me. +1 for you.

Comment: Can you explain me the function of \clip?

Comment: It is used for clipping subsequent drawings in the same scope. See TikZ manual page 608.

Answer (score 9):

I have drawn the curve in another way below :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (3cm);
\draw (-3,0) arc (180:360:3cm and 1cm);
\draw[dashed] (-3,0) arc (180:0:3cm and 1cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]