# Draw parallels of a sphere with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to draw properly parallels of a sphere properly? The equator is ok:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[ball color=blue!20] (0,0) circle (1.5);
\draw [thick,dotted] plot [domain=0:pi] ({1.5*cos(\x r)},{0.2*sin(\x r)},0);
\draw [thick] plot [domain=pi:2*pi] ({1.5*cos(\x r)},{0.2*sin(\x r)},0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Yet the other parallels are tricky to put in place.

Comment: What does "parallels of a sphere" mean?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42812/3d-bodies-in-tikz

Comment: I mean circles of latitude, like on the Earth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[ball color=blue!20] (0,0) circle (1.5 cm);
\newcommand\latitude[1]{%
  \draw (#1:1.5) arc (0:-180:{1.5*cos(#1)} and {0.2*cos(#1)});
  \draw[dashed] (#1:1.5) arc (0:180:{1.5*cos(#1)} and {0.2*cos(#1)});
}
\latitude{30};
\latitude{0};
\latitude{-30};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: latitudes]

It can be improved, by making the radius(1.5 and 0.2) variables.

Answer (score 5):

You can use package `tikz-3dplot-circleofsphere` at  [here](https://github.com/matthias-wolff/tikz-3dplot-circleofsphere)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm, 12 pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot-circleofsphere}
\begin{document}
 \def\r{3}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{125}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\begin{scope}
\fill[ball color=blue!20,tdplot_screen_coords] (0,0,0) circle (\r);
\tdplotCsDrawLatCircle{\r}{0}
\end{scope}
\foreach  \a in {-75,-60,...,75}  
\tdplotCsDrawLatCircle[tdplotCsFront/.style={black}]{\r}{\a};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]