# debugging tikz: how assign each separate tikz object to a variable and then add them to a picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

To help me learn Tikz, I thought it will help, if I can draw each Tikz "object" (the thing that ends with a ";") on its own, then at the end, send them all to tikzpicture to see the whole objects put together. I do this all the time in Mathematica, but I can't get the syntax right with Latex/Tikz.

Let me explain little more, then give a MWE.  Suppose I want to draw this picture, which is made of 3 separate objects (the code is from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42812/3d-bodies-in-tikz))

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-1,0) arc (180:360:1cm and 0.5cm) -- (0,3) -- cycle;
    \draw[dashed] (-1,0) arc (180:0:1cm and 0.5cm);
    \shade[left color=blue!5!white,right color=blue!40!white,opacity=0.3]
            (-1,0) arc (180:360:1cm and 0.5cm) -- (0,3) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I'd like to draw each object on its own picture, so I can see how they look like. So I need to assign each object to a variable, to avoid copy/pasting same code. i.e. I'd like to do something like this (which does not work, since syntax is not right) but just to give an idea what I want to do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newbool{debug} \setbool{debug}{true}  %flag for debugging
\begin{document}

%syntax error., Argument of \a has an extra }. }{}
\newcommand{\a}{\draw (-1,0) arc (180:360:1cm and 0.5cm) -- (0,3) -- cycle}
\newcommand{\b}{\draw[dashed] (-1,0) arc (180:0:1cm and 0.5cm)}
\newcommand{\z}{\shade[left color=blue!5!white,right 
    color=blue!40!white,opacity=0.3](-1,0) 
        arc (180:360:1cm and 0.5cm) -- (0,3) -- cycle}


\ifbool{debug}
{
  \tikz{\a}
  \tikz{\b}
  \tikz{\z}
 }{}

\begin{tikzpicture}  %now put things all together, once get the syntax right
    \a;
    \b;
    \z;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The above is what I'd like to do. Now, I do this (copy/paste same code)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newbool{debug} \setbool{debug}{true}  %flag for debugging

\begin{document}

\ifbool{debug}
{
\tikz{\draw (-1,0) arc (180:360:1cm and 0.5cm) -- (0,3) -- cycle}
\tikz{\draw[dashed] (-1,0) arc (180:0:1cm and 0.5cm)}
\tikz{\shade[left color=blue!5!white,right color=blue!40!white,opacity=0.3]
            (-1,0) arc (180:360:1cm and 0.5cm) -- (0,3) -- cycle}
}{}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-1,0) arc (180:360:1cm and 0.5cm) -- (0,3) -- cycle;
    \draw[dashed] (-1,0) arc (180:0:1cm and 0.5cm);
    \shade[left color=blue!5!white,right color=blue!40!white,opacity=0.3]
            (-1,0) arc (180:360:1cm and 0.5cm) -- (0,3) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I tried using `\def` also, but many syntax errors as well. I am newbie.

Comment: Nothing to do with tikz you can not use numbers in command names in TeX  this defines `\g` to be `1` : `\let\g1\{`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you are right, I forgot this, I read it 3 days ago in the manual. I'll fix it now. thanks

Comment: and of course the syntax for \let is just two tokens `\let\a\b` you can not use `\let` with a brace group, use `\newcommand`

Comment: `\let\a\{` defines `\a` to be `\{` You may be new to tikz, but all the usual tex commands have the meaning they had before:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ok, ok, I am all confused by all these syntaxes, that is why I asked. Will change it to use \newcommand, but still get an syntax error :)  thanks

Comment: The error message is pretty self explanatory `LaTeX Error: Command \a already defined` `\a` is already defined, call your commands `\za` `\zb` `\zz`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is pretty self explanatory:

```
 LaTeX Error: Command \a already defined
```

call your commands `\za \zb \zz` then it works as you intended.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newbool{debug} \setbool{debug}{true}  %flag for debugging
\begin{document}

%syntax error., Argument of \a has an extra }. }{}
\newcommand{\za}{\draw (-1,0) arc (180:360:1cm and 0.5cm) -- (0,3) -- cycle}
\newcommand{\zb}{\draw[dashed] (-1,0) arc (180:0:1cm and 0.5cm);}
\newcommand{\zz}{\shade[left color=blue!5!white,right color=blue!40!white,opacity=0.3]
            (-1,0) arc (180:360:1cm and 0.5cm) -- (0,3) -- cycle;}


\ifbool{debug}
{
  \tikz{\za}
  \tikz{\zb}
  \tikz{\zz}
 }{}

\begin{tikzpicture}  %now put things all together, once get the syntax right
    \za;
    \zb;
    \zz;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```