# What would be a good way to make a TikZ picture composed of lines, dots and cones?

Tags: diagrams

I want to make a diagram like this:

[image]

It features lines, dots and 3D cones. I'd also like it to feature a little "explosion" icon and text labels.

I have seen some examples of how to make 3D cones ([3D bodies in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42812/3d-bodies-in-tikz)), but I'm not sure how one should make a big ensemble of features like this. What would be a good way to approach this?

Comment: This example looks like a starting point: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/skype-topology/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to approach this would be the following:

1. Spend some time going through the TikZ manual and studying some examples.
2. Get started drawing the basic structure, like the lines, dots, and starburst (explosion icon).
3. Try to incorporate the 3D cones to which you linked.
4. If you get stuck, come back here and post a more appropriate question, providing an MWE or what you've come up with so far to give others a starting point. See [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Regarding the "come back here and post a more appropriate question", the point of the question is to avoid completing a massive amount of work (creating huge numbers of nodes, for example) only to be told there is a better approach. The point is that I'm not looking for guidance on the minutiae (like cones); I'm looking for guidance on what drawing framework I should be using. For example, would a [graph](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/graph/) be appropriate for a drawing like this?

Comment: @d3pd Your question comes across as another "Can someone do this complicated drawing for me?" kind of question (which is probably why it was initially downvoted). Perhaps it would be better to ask something like "Is there a more suitable package than TikZ to draw this figure?"

Comment: Think of this as a good way to learn how to use the wonderful TikZ package.