# Draw a balanced fulcrum with cylinder, pyramid and sphere

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I have been drawn the following figure, showing that the sphere with radius R and cone with base radius 2R and height 2R, away from the pivot with distance 2R, is rotational equilibrium with cylinder that has base radius and height of 2R.

[image]

The lengths are indicated in the figure above, and the red dots represent the centre of masses of the objects.

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    %Wall
    \draw [fill,pattern=north east lines,draw=none] (-3,3) rectangle (3,3.25);
    \draw (-3,3)--(3,3);
    
    %Segment
    \draw[|<->|]  (-2,2.45) -- (0.67,2.45) node[midway,fill=white] {$2R$};
    \draw[|<->|]  (0.67,2.45) -- (2,2.45) node[midway,fill=white] {$R$};
    \draw[|<->|]  (4,1) -- (4,-0.5) node[midway,fill=white] {$2R$};
    \draw[|<->|]  (-0.5,1) -- (-0.5,-1) node[midway,fill=white] {$2R$};
    \draw[|<->|]  (-0.5,-2) -- (-0.5,-4) node[midway,fill=white] {$2R$};
    \draw[|<->|]  (4,1) -- (4,-0.5) node[midway,fill=white] {$2R$};
    \draw[|<->|]  (1,1.25) -- (2,1.25) node[midway,fill=white] {$R$};
    \draw[|<->|]  (3,1.25) -- (2,1.25) node[midway,fill=white] {$R$};
    
    %Fulcrum
    \draw[thick, fill=yellow, yellow] (-2.01,2) rectangle (2.01,2.25);
    
    %Lines hanging objects
    \draw[thick] (-2,2)--(-2,1)  (0.67,2.25)--(0.67,3) (-2,-1)--(-2,-2) (2,1)--(2,2);
    
    %Sphere
    \draw (-3,0) arc (180:360:1cm and 0.5cm);
    \draw[dashed] (-3,0) arc (180:0:1cm and 0.5cm);
    \draw (-2,1) arc (90:270:0.5cm and 1cm);
    \draw[dashed] (-2,1) arc (90:-90:0.5cm and 1cm);
    \draw (-2,0) circle (1cm);
    \shade[ball color=blue!10!white,opacity=0.20] (-2,0) circle (1cm);
    \tkzDefPoint(-2,0){A} 
    \tkzDrawPoints[color=red, fill=red](A)
    
    %Cone
    \draw (-3,-4) arc (180:360:1cm and 0.5cm) -- (-2,-2) -- cycle;
    \draw[dashed] (-3,-4) arc (180:0:1cm and 0.5cm);
    \shade[left color=blue!5!white,right color=blue!40!white,opacity=0.3] (-3,-4) arc (180:360:1cm and 0.5cm) -- (-2,-2) -- cycle;
    \draw (-2,-4)--(-1,-4);
    \node at (-1.5,-3.7) {$2R$};
     \tkzDefPoint(-2,-3){B} 
    \tkzDrawPoints[color=red, fill=red](B)
    
    %Cylinder
    \draw (1,1) arc (90:270:0.75cm and 1.5cm);
    \draw[dashed] (1,1) arc (90:-90:0.75cm and 1.5cm);
    \draw (3,1) arc (90:270:0.75cm and 1.5cm);
    \draw (3,1) arc (90:-90:0.75cm and 1.5cm);
    \draw (1,1)--(3,1) (1,-2)--(3,-2);
    \shade[left color=green!5!white,right color=green!40!white,opacity=0.3] (1,1) arc (90:270:0.75cm and 1.5cm)--(1,-2)--(3,-2)--(3,-2) arc (-90:90:0.75cm and 1.5cm)--cycle;
    \tkzDefPoint(2,-0.5){C} 
    \tkzDrawPoints[color=red, fill=red](C)
    
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

On the other hand, I would like to take infinitesimal thickness of Δx, away with distance x (in blue) as shown in below:

[image]

It seems there would be hard to take the infinitesimal thickness of Δx for sphere since it is hard to calculate the height of a small portion explicitly. Is there any ways to draw it nicely?

Comment: Hi, maybe you can try to start with https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42812/3d-bodies-in-tikz

Comment: @Colo I have edited the post after refer to your guidance. But the figure is not that smooth to me.

Comment: Could you develop your question? My uncertainties: 1) Is there a connection between your blue curves and the centers of mass?  2) Is the final drawing close to reality?  Are the two $\Delta x$ on the left and $\Delta x$ on the right different such that the blue volumes verify the formula $2(V(sphere)+V(cone))=V(cylinder)$?  By the way, the cone 's center of mass is not correctly placed.

Comment: Note that the drawing of your sphere is not in equilibrium position, because
the string is **not** fixed at the pole.
In your drawing you shall only see the north pole, but not the south
pole which shall be behind the contour.
See <https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b3/Ello-u12.svg>.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,3dtools}% https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d/install view={phi=110,theta=70},line join = round, line cap = round,declare function={R=3;r=R;h=R;}]
        \path
        (0,0,0) coordinate (O)
        (0,0,R)  coordinate (N)
        (0,0,-R)  coordinate (S)
(0,0,3) coordinate (T);
    \begin{scope}[3d/install view={phi=120,psi=0,
        theta=70}]
    \draw[3d/screen coords] (O) circle[radius=R]; 
    \path pic{3d/circle on sphere={R=R,C={(0,0,0)},n={(0,0,1)}}}
    ; 
    \path pic{3d/circle on sphere={R=R,C={(O)}}};
\path  pic{3d/circle on sphere={R=R,C={(O)},P={(O)}, n={(1,-5,0)}}};

\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
\path (0,0,-4*R)
pic{3d/cone={r=R,h/.evaluated=2*R}};
\draw[3d/hidden] (N) -- (0,0,-4*R); 
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=5cm,3d/install view={phi=10,theta=70,psi=0}]
    \path[3d/record physical components] 
    (1,0,0) coordinate (ez') 
    (0,1,0) coordinate (ex') 
    (0,0,1) coordinate (ey');
    \begin{scope}[x={(ex')},y={(ey')},z={(ez')}]
    \pic{3d/frustum={r=r,R=r,h=2*R}};
    \end{scope}
\end{scope}     
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]