# Cabinet projection in PSTricks

Tags: pstricks

I would like to draw pictures in [cabinet projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblique_projection#Cabinet_projection) in PSTricks. This is close to `coorType=2`, but I need shorten the oblique axis by factor `1/2` rather than `1/sqrt(2)`. Is there any way how to arrange this?

Reated question is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37442/draw-a-prism-in-tikz-or-pstricks) but the answer in PSTricks contains `coorType=2`, i.e. the scaling factor is not what I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with `pst-3dplot.pro` from http://texnik.dante.de/dvips/pst-3dplot/ you can use `coorType=5`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}

\begin{document}

\psset{coorType=2,Alpha=90,
    IIIDxTicksPlane=yz}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(3,3)
\pstThreeDCoor[IIIDticks,zMax=3]%
\end{pspicture}

\bigskip
\psset{coorType=5,Alpha=30,
    IIIDxTicksPlane=yz}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(3,3)
\pstThreeDCoor[IIIDticks,zMax=3]%
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]