# How to draw cubes in PSTricks with dashed hidden lines?

Tags: pst-3dplot

I'd like to draw cubes with PSTricks (pst-3dplot) as shown in the related question [Draw a prism in TikZ or PSTricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37442/draw-a-prism-in-tikz-or-pstricks) like these two

[image: two cubes]

with correct hidden lines, but with the code given there (Simple Boxes with `pst-3dplot`),

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\begin{document}   
\psset{coorType=1,Alpha=135}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-2)(5,2.25)
%\pstThreeDCoor[xMin=-1,xMax=4,yMin=-1,yMax=4,zMin=-1,zMax=4]
\pstThreeDBox[hiddenLine=false](0,0,0)(0,0,3)(3,0,0)(0,3,0)
\end{pspicture}
%
\psset{coorType=2}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-2)(2,2.25)
%\pstThreeDCoor[xMin=-1,xMax=4,yMin=-1,yMax=4,zMin=-1,zMax=4]
\pstThreeDBox[hiddenLine](0,0,0)(0,0,3)(3,0,0)(0,3,0)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

I don't get the wanted results: Only four lines (of the 6 most outer ones) are drawn as solid lines, all other lines are drawn as dashed lines:

[image: cube]

Using macro `in/visibleLineStyle=dashed/solid` didn't help.

What's going wrong?

Wolfgang

Now it works! But if I use coordinate system 6,

```
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-2)(5,5)
\psset{coorType=2}
\pstThreeDBox[linewidth=1.1pt](0,0,0)(0,0,3)(3,0,0)(0,3,0)
\end{pspicture}
%
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-2)(5,5)
\psset{coorType=6}
\pstThreeDBox[linewidth=1.1pt](0,0,0)(0,0,3)(3,0,0)(0,3,0)
\end{pspicture}
```

I get again a wrong result:

[image: two cubes]

Comment: You could take a look at the `pst-solides3d` package…

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 4):

With the version 2.03 from http://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/texnik/tex/generic/pst-3dplot/  you'll get:

[image]

Comment: Now it works! But if I use coordinate system 6 (`\psset{coorType=6}`), I get again a wrong result (se above).

Comment: the whole stuff needs some rewriting which will take some time. You can try the experimental version from http://texnik.dante.de/tex/generic/pst-3dplot/ which I updated in the morning.